# Error on line 26 "Called object type "int" is not function or function pointer? why is this occuring?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

"Type called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer" the error is coming up on line 26 which is my formula.
 I can't determine the origin of the error, please help.

```
      11   #include <stdio.h>
      12   #include <stdlib.h>
      13   #include <math.h>
      14    
      15   int main()        
      16        double p1, ac, at, p2, p3, ar, p;
      17        int code;
      18        p=(p1+p2+p3)/2;
      19        setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
      20    
      21        while(1){
      22            printf("Enter code and parameter(s) (Code=0 to Quit):");
      23            scanf("%d%lf%lf%lf", &code, &p1, &p2, &p3);
      24            if(code==0) break;
      25            if(code==1){
      26                ac=2*M_PI*(p1*p1);
      27                printf("area of circle: %f", ac);
      28            }
      29            else if(code==2){
      30                at=sqrt(p*(p-p1)*(p-p2)*(p-p3));
      31                printf("area of triangle: %f", at);
      32            }
      33            else if(code==3){
      34                ar=p1*p2;
      35                printf("area of rectangle: %f", ar);
      36            }
      37            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
      38        }
      39    }
```

Comment: By the way, why not use `switch(code)` instead of the cascaded `if`?

Comment: A proper C library does not define `M_PI` in `<math.h>`.  For debug, try `ac=2*3.14*(p1*p1);`

Comment: @chux quite right, but an XSI-conformant math.h *will* define `M_PI` if you have `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` prior to any system header include. Probably this program doesn't.

Comment: You do not initialize `p` with a useful value `p=(p1+p2+p3)/2;` At this point the values of `p1`, `p2` and `p3` are undefined. You only read them later in your loop but do not update `p`.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the opening brace after `main`:

```
int main() {
    double p1, ac, at, p2, p3, ar, p;
    ...
```

Comment: I realized that after posting thanks

Comment: But that's not line 26, so I'm confused!

Comment: @KeeganEdwards Please confirm if the code we discuss is the code that causes your error, and the error is still on line 26.

Comment: This is typical of this type of error.  C will go as far is it can trying to figure out what you're doing and then just give up with a weirdly attributed error.  Missing semi-colons can produce the same weirdness.  It's not the compiler so much as the parser/tokenizer trying to make sense of what you have and misinterpreting it when applying the CFG.